# Exception polymorphism c++

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance

I have made my own exception class which derives from `runtime_error` and is getting an int in the c'tor.

I would like to make a base class for this exception, in order to use polymorphism, so I could catch only the base class and basically I would be catching the derived class.

So, this is the base class: (and in another cpp file I got baseException::~baseException(){})

```
class baseException
{
    virtual ~baseException()=0 {}
};
```

And this is the derived class:

```
class myException: public runtime_error, public baseException
{
public:
    myException(int): runtime_error("Error occured") {}
};
```

Note that I do not have any actual error in the base class, it's only role is to enable me polymorphism on my future custom exception classes I will make.
That is why it only has a pure virtual d'tor. I do not need any "actual" object of this `BaseException` class.

Though, when I try to catch baseException in the main and call what(), I can not.
How do I make it work?

Comment: Please define 'does not work'. What did you expect, what did you get?

Comment: added some of the errors, but thats not the point. by the amount of errors i guess im totally off the way, so I ask here to that should be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you're missing the `()` from the destructor's declaration, and there's a rogue `:` after the class name.

Once you've fixed that, you'll probably get an error like:

```
error: pure-specifier on function-definition
```

For some reason known only to the C++ standards committee, pure virtual functions cannot be implemented within the class definition like that. If you want it to be pure virtual, then you'll need to move the definition outside the class:

```
class baseException
{
    virtual ~baseException()=0;
};

inline baseException::~baseException() {}
```

You'll also need to decide whether `myException` derives from `runtime_exception` or `runtime_error`: you use one in the class header, and the other in the constructor's initialiser list. Assuming you're using the standard exception types, it should probably by `std::runtime_error` (and, if there's a `using namespace std;` in your header file, then you should remove it to avoid breaking code that doesn't expect the global namespace to be polluted like that).

Comment: ty, fixed all the problems but it seems that I need to make a "what()" method for base class. is it truth? how?

Comment: @Jjang: If you want to access `std::exception::what()`, then perhaps you should be catching `std::exception const &`, rather than your own base class.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you need parentheses and a non-inline definition for your destructor.

Also, you derive from `runtime_exception` (from AMP library?) but call the constructor of `runtime_error` (from `std` namespace I assume).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about parenthesis. It should be

```
virtual ~baseException()=0 {}
```

Comment: Pure specifiers are not allowed on inline function definitions. The dtor must be defined out of line.

Comment: And there is a `:` too much after `class baseException`.